# htaccess redirection in php

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

How can i redirect from www.example.com/dietitian/reema.verma.3 to www.example.com/dietitian/#/3 ? Please help.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
Redirect www.example.com/dietitian/reema.verma.3 www.example.com/dietitian/#/3
```

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: yes. see I just edit my question. But it is not working. I put the above code in .htaccess file. And place the .htaccess file at the root folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only match `REQUEST_URI` using `RewriteRule` or `Redirect`.

Use this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?(dietitian)/.+\.(\d+)/?$ /project/$1/#/$2 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: it is redirecting from http://localhost/project/dietitian/reema.verma.23 to http://localhost/dietitian/#/23

Comment: please suggest what to do

Comment: No, now it is redirecting to http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/project/dietitian/#/23

Comment: Yes. Great. Thanks Anubhava. :)

Comment: Hi anubhava, Please help there is some change in requirement
now I want
www.example.com/healthcare/practitioner/nikky.23 to www.example.com/healthcare/practitioner/#/nikky.23

Comment: No.. It is doing infinite page loading. And not showing anything after /#/

Comment: Sorry try this rule: `RewriteRule ^/?(healthcare/practitioner)/(.+)$ /$1/#/$2 [L,NC,R=301,NE]` and clear your browser cache.

Comment: I have tested in on my Apache and that's not happening in my testing. If error persists please open a new question with all the details.

Comment: Ok I will. I don't why it is even after redirecting saying Maximum call stack size exceeded.